# failed to load resource

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-server

When my site loads i get error in console

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
http://mtserver:80/test/_catalogs/masterpage/scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js
```

I went to my master page gallery and checked if files are there and i can see that they are present. So dont understand why its complaining. Can somebody please help me?

I have defined scripts in below manner in my master page

```
<script src="/test/_catalogs/masterpage/scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What is the root of the site collection in this case? http://mtserver:80/test or http://mtserver:80

Comment: @EricAlexander mtserver:80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one masterpage gallery for the site collection, and that is at the root, so you have an invalid reference. It should be:

```
<script src="/_catalogs/masterpage/scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```